# Generate Background for Each Post With Wordpress Thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a [website](http://palatehack.com) that i'm working on where I need to generate a unique image in header.php for each individual post.

I have this in my index.php:

```
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
 foreach($pageposts as $ppost){
$ID = $ppost->post_id;
$title = get_the_title( $ID ); 
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $ID ), 'single_post_thumbnail' );
$t = $thumb[0];
$desc = get_post($ID)->post_content;
$out = get_post_meta($ID,'outbound',true);
$output = "
<div class='ph-sticky' id='phf'>
<span class='icon-x'><i class='fa fa-times icon-xy'></i></span>
<div class='row hunt-row-fp'>
<a class='title' href='$out' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>$title</a>
<div class='img-featured'><img class='phsi' src='$t'/></div>
<span class='description'>$desc</span>
</div>
</div>";    
 }

 echo $output;
 wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This correctly generates a thumbnail for each post, however in my header.php my code only generates the image of the FIRST post on the page. Here it is:

```
<!-- post modal -->
<div class="show-post-modal">  

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
<div class="comments-bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')" >
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="comments-header">
```

I've tried multiple solutions however I can only seem to pull in the first thumbnail, which becomes the background for all posts. Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you a lot.

```
<?php 
$page = get_post($post->ID);
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
if(!empty($post_thumbnail_id)) {
$img_ar =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'full' );?>
<style>
.comments-bg-image{ background-image: url(<?php echo $img_ar[0];?>);  }
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, this fails to return the image URL at all unfortunately. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should add the css: comments-bg-image{ background-size: 100%; }

Comment: i have no doubt for my solutions. it must work even you found problem then you need to describe so i can get and come to know the real situations.

Comment: Thanks @Anand for responding. It still only shows the first image, is it possible that we need to set this earlier? I'm unsure how this doesn't work however the page thumbnails all generate correctly.

Comment: Actually this not generates your thumbnail this will display the thumbnail as your page's/post's background even you can modify the code and set the default image if you have not set the thumbnail.